# SPSS how to turn variables with specific answers and their values into a new variable

Tags: spss

I'd like to know how to turn different variables with specific values into a new category variable to extend the specific values? I tried it with compute a variable to get a new one but it didn't work:

this is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
DO IF ((Q103_01=>3) AND (Q103_05=>3) AND (Q201_06=<2) AND (Q201_07=<2) AND (Q201_08=<2) AND (Q301_06=<2) AND (Q301_07=<2) AND (Q301_08=<2) AND (Q305_04=2) AND (Q305_06=2) AND (Q409_05=1) AND (Q407_07=<2) AND (Q408_04=1) AND (Q408_05=1) AND (Q411_02=<2) AND (Q203_04=<2) AND (Q203_06=<2) AND (Q203_07=<2) AND (Q203_09=<2) AND (Q203_10=<2)).
  COMPUTE NewVariable = 1. 
END IF. 
EXECUTE.
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Your example would be more helpful if you added a sample of the data itself, including what the target variable should look like. In any case - the line of syntax you posted is flawed and wouldn't work, my guess is you only posted part of the line? please post the complete command so we can better understand what you're trying to do and help find the problem...

Comment: I'd like to create a new variable out of these variables with their values: Q103_01=4; Q103_05=4; Q201_06=1; Q201_07=1; Q201_08=1;Q301_06=1;Q301_07=1; Q301_08=1; Q305_04=2; Q305_06=2;Q409_05=1;Q407_07=1;Q408_04=1;Q408_05=1;Q411_02=1;Q203_04=1; Q203_06=1; Q203_07=1;
Q203_09=1; Q203_10=1. so if a person answered in question 103_01=4 AND in the following questions like above, the person should be counted in category x, otherwise in another category. The questions have differents scales.

Comment: Please explain also what didn't work - what results did you get and how are they different than what you expected?

Comment: while you're at it - `DO IF` isn't needed here - just `if cond1 and cond2 and cond3 newvar=1`.

Comment: the results are that the function counts everyone and not just the persons that answered like the expected conditions. also the "sequence of operators found is invalid". Thanks a lot I'll try it with your suggestion!

Comment: I tried it with your code and without =</> and just with =/>/< and it wrked!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using "Less than or equal to" or "Greater than or equal to" the sequence should be `<=` (or `LE`), `>=` (or `GE`).
The error message came from using `=>` instead of `>=`.
Otherwise your syntax should work fine.
But it can be written more efficiently this way:

```
if cond1 and cond2 and cond3 newvar=1.
```

without using `do if`.